# Angular 2 ngfor loop the value is the youtube link or another link?

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript

```
<li  *ngFor="let post of posts ;let i = index ">
  <div  *ngIf="post.link != ''">
    <iframe width="100%" height="315" frameborder="0" [src]="post.link">
     </iframe>
  </div>
</li>
```

The **post.link** is **youtube** Link or another website link,

if the **post.link** is without youtube link **hide the iframe tag.**

Comment: I think your question has nothing to do with being in a `ngFor` or not.

Comment: change `*ngIf="post.link != ''"` to `*ngIf="post.link && post.link != ''"`

Comment: whats the question? as of the ng-if check you can specify a function and check if the link contains something like youtu.be or youtube.com

Comment: you can try *ngIf="post.link.indexOf('youtube.com') != -1 "

Comment: *ngIf="post.link.indexOf('youtube.com') != -1 " is working and simple solution .

Answer (score 1):

One option.
Give your posts an extra key eg: isYoutube(boolean)

So then you can edit your ngFor:

```
<iframe *ngIf="post.isYoutube" width="100%" height="315" frameborder="0" [src]="post.link"></iframe>
<a *ngIf="!post.isYoutube">{{post.link}}</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're looking for something like :

**HTML**

```
<div *ngIf="isYoutube(post)">
  <iframe width="100%" height="315" frameborder="0" [src]="post.link"></iframe>
</div>
```

**Component**

```
isYoutube(post: Post): boolean {
  return post && post.link && -1 < post.link.indexOf('youtu');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check that link for a post doesn't contain "youtube.com" with

```
*ngIf="post.link.indexOf('youtube.com') != -1"
```